# MVC: Dynamically populate html select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

I have a field that is generated for each row in the view as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MenuParentKey, ViewBag.MenuKeys as SelectList)
```

But I want the drop-down to be populated for each row individually, by calling an action in the controller, here is what I mean:

```
public ActionResult GetMenuKeys(string currentMenuKey)
{
  var dictionary = MenuKeys.Where(mk => mk.Key != currentMenuKey);

  return View(new SelectList(dictionary,
      "Key",
      "Value",
      Page.DefaultParentKey));
}
```

`currentMenuKey` should be provided according to current row, I want the value of the current row to be excluded from the drop-down (notice it's the *parent-key* property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a Helper that would return a `SelectList` instead.

That would allow you the call it directly from your view, you would also be able to pass the parameter as required.

I think that would be easier than calling an action on your controler.

From what I see here, the controler action does not fetch any other resources than the list.

You could go with something like this :

```
public static SelectList FilteredList( this HtmlHelper helper, MenuKeys keys, string CurrentMenuKey)
{
var dictionary = MenuKeys.Where(mk => mk.Key != currentMenuKey);

  return new SelectList(dictionary,
      "Key",
      "Value",
      Page.DefaultParentKey);
}
```

Then you could call it this way :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MenuParentKey, Html.FilteredList(ViewBag.MenuKeys as SelectList, m.currentKey))
```